# React Native: Flex behaving differently

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';

class First extends Component {
render () {
    return (
        <View style = {styles.container}>
            <Text>
                Hello world!
            </Text>
        </View>
    );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
container: {
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    flex: 1
}
});


module.exports = First;
```

This code fills the screen with yellow in projects started with `react-native init` but shows nothing in projects started with `create-react-native-app`. Is this normal?

Edit: This was mistakenly called from a styled `View` in the main App.js.

Comment: "_but doesn't do the same_", what else does it do?

Comment: @KhalilKhalaf It shows nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Stupid mistake; I was calling this component from a styled `View` of the main App.js. Thanks for taking the time to help out, guys.

Answer (score 0):

it will help you

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-    
native';

class First extends Component {
render () {
return (
    <View>
        <Text style = {styles.container}>
            Hello world!
        </Text>
    </View>
   );
  }
  }

 const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
 container: {
 backgroundColor: 'yellow',
 flex: 1
 }
});


module.exports = First;
```

Comment: That returns the same result.

Comment: Use color instead of backgroundcolor

Answer (score 0):

I used your code, and create app using `create-react-native-app`and show yellow background color with text `hello world!` on top left

here the result that i had [the-result-using-create-react-native-app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMwkH.png)

maybe you should create another test app using `create-react-native-add` command and see the result